# Write bitmap to array instead of file stream in Android

Tags: android, arrays, bitmap

Currently, when I want to save a bitmap to disk I use:

```
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
```

Is it possible to have the data written to a byte array instead? I need to manipulate the data that goes to disk and not just the bitmap's image data. The jpg consist of additional stuff like metadata. I don't really care that it's a jpg. I'm not interested in what the data is but just to access the entire data that would normally get written to disk.

Comment: And remember that large Bitmaps could cause OutOfMemoryErrors - so careful with that.

Comment: Shiv, can you post that as a solution instead of a comment please and I'll give you the checkmark.

Comment: @AndroidDev-yeah i have posted it as an ans you can mark it if it helped you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this code :

```
      ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                bMap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
                byte[] imageArray = out.toByteArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using:

```
public byte[] convertBitmapToByteArray(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream(bitmap.getWidth() * bitmap.getHeight());
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, buffer);
    return buffer.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: That is wrong. You are creating an array the size of the image. The data written to disk contains, as mentioned, metadata and all the other stuff that goes into a jpg. Remove the sizing and it will work.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to preserve the original pixel data (without compression), you can try this:

```
public byte[] bitmapToByteArray(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bitmap.getByteCount());
    bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(byteBuffer);
    return byteBuffer.array();
}
```

Comment: That just copies the pixels and doesn't include the rest of the jpg information.

Comment: @AndroidDev you said in your question "I don't really care that it's a jpg.".

Comment: I wrote "I need to manipulate the data that goes to disk and not just the bitmap's image data." - That was clear. It could be a png, jpg, whatever.

Answer (score -1):

```
U can try this.

if (Utility.isWifiPresent()
                    || Utility.isMobileConnectionPresent()) {
                URL url = new URL(fileUrl);
                InputStream iStream = url.openConnection().getInputStream();// .read(data)
                ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                byte[] tmpArray = new byte[1024];
                int nRead;
                while ((nRead = iStream.read(tmpArray, 0, tmpArray.length)) != -1) {
                    buffer.write(tmpArray, 0, nRead);
                }
                buffer.flush();
                data = buffer.toByteArray();
                FileOutputStream fOut = null;
        //path to store

                    fOut = Utility.getFileOutputStreamForCloud(
                            sdcardFolderPath, fileUrl);
                }
                fOut.write(data);
                fOut.flush();
                fOut.close();
```